# Vagrant + VB + Nginx: loses forwarded port on redirect

Tags: nginx, debian, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant VirtualBox running with nginx. Port 80 is forwarded to 8099. The problem is, if there's a redirect, let's say `mysite.dev:8099/admin` redirects to `/login`, the server port gets lost. My (temporary) solution is to address mysite.dev to the ip of the virtual machine instead of the host machine (e.g. 192.168.1.101 instead of 127.0.0.1) in `/etc/hosts`, this way, I don't have to deal with the forwarded http port.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: How is the 80 to 8099 port forwarding being done? You would expect that when when you are redirected to `/login`, this should be forwarded to `:8099/login` by whatever mechanism is handling the forwarding.

Comment: Port forwarding is handled by vagrant/VirtualBox. I don't know how the application handles redirects. I guess it redirects to a full URL instead of a relative URI (which would work).